# Flex over https not showing

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, https

I have a situation here that pretty much seems to me that it´s a security configuration issue.

My flex app runs over https in any browser. But it is not working properly in this context:

- Windows 2008 Server
- Internet Explorer
- Via TS connection

If any of these is changed, it works. In the server side I see that everything is ok, the flex is provided and even it´s communications happens but the ***browser shows nothing***.

Anybody got that kind of behavirou, I really think it is a configuration.

Comment: Can you quantify "not working"  What is not working?  Are you receiving errors?  Or something else?

Comment: I guess I wrote this information without the proper highlight, now I bolded it. The browser shows nothing, the screen remains white. No errors are shown.

Comment: I see it now; my mistake.  I'm not sure what the issue is.  Most likely something with the Terminal Services connection.

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed numerous Flash/Flex applications over https, and they all work flawlessly.

From my experience, you can look into the following areas:

1. Does Flash request data from the server?  If so, does it use http or https?  If it uses relative path requesting data, then it should inherit the current security context.
2. When deployed anything under https, it is important to make sure every assets are loaded using https, or some browser security setting would prevent those assets from loading correctly.  These assets may include javascript, css for the page, or RSL's that the SWF may depend on.

Troubleshooting the issue is not hard, you can use Fiddler for Windows or Charles Proxy for Mac, turn on the https proxy bypass, and observe the traffic.  You would then see any 404, or 500 errors that may lead to solution.

Comment: Another thing to check: there could be issues is the SWF is accessing SSL services that use a self signed certificate that was not loaded into the browser's "approved certificates" collection.

Comment: I deploy numerous Flash/Flex apps too. But note that the situation is really specific. It happens in a Win2008Server, in IE and ONLY when accessing this windows machine over Terminal Service. If I go physically in the same machine it works properly.

Comment: The answer for your first question is Yes. As noted in my question, the server log shows data being served to the client.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in your second question, I´ll test it. +1 for that. Thanks.